# Make circles match same color filtering as multi-line on d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a multi-line graph that updates when filtered by each fruit. Each line color corresponds to a different year of sales. With the help of [Shashank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5569282/shashank), the circles on the line for each data-point have been added to the group  instead of appending directly to the SVG. Here's a snippet showing this:

```js
var dataAsCsv = `Month,Sales,Fruit,Year
Jan,87,strawberry,2016
Feb,3,strawberry,2016
Mar,89,strawberry,2016
Apr,56,strawberry,2016
May,1,strawberry,2016
Jun,17,strawberry,2016
Jul,59,strawberry,2016
Aug,43,strawberry,2016
Sep,16,strawberry,2016
Oct,94,strawberry,2016
Nov,99,strawberry,2016
Dec,53,strawberry,2016
Jan,93,grape,2016
Feb,8,grape,2016
Mar,95,grape,2016
Apr,62,grape,2016
May,5,grape,2016
Jun,24,grape,2016
Jul,62,grape,2016
Aug,49,grape,2016
Sep,18,grape,2016
Oct,101,grape,2016
Nov,103,grape,2016
Dec,53,grape,2016
Jan,94,blueberry,2016
Feb,15,blueberry,2016
Mar,95,blueberry,2016
Apr,64,blueberry,2016
May,11,blueberry,2016
Jun,33,blueberry,2016
Jul,64,blueberry,2016
Aug,53,blueberry,2016
Sep,27,blueberry,2016
Oct,103,blueberry,2016
Nov,108,blueberry,2016
Dec,62,blueberry,2016
Jan,80,strawberry,2015
Feb,0,strawberry,2015
Mar,71,strawberry,2015
Apr,51,strawberry,2015
May,3,strawberry,2015
Jun,11,strawberry,2015
Jul,56,strawberry,2015
Aug,34,strawberry,2015
Sep,12,strawberry,2015
Oct,75,strawberry,2015
Nov,94,strawberry,2015
Dec,46,strawberry,2015
Jan,76,grape,2015
Feb,0,grape,2015
Mar,78,grape,2015
Apr,58,grape,2015
May,10,grape,2015
Jun,22,grape,2015
Jul,47,grape,2015
Aug,36,grape,2015
Sep,18,grape,2015
Oct,86,grape,2015
Nov,98,grape,2015
Dec,40,grape,2015
Jan,79,blueberry,2015
Feb,0,blueberry,2015
Mar,78,blueberry,2015
Apr,49,blueberry,2015
May,5,blueberry,2015
Jun,31,blueberry,2015
Jul,62,blueberry,2015
Aug,49,blueberry,2015
Sep,7,blueberry,2015
Oct,86,blueberry,2015
Nov,100,blueberry,2015
Dec,46,blueberry,2015`;


// Set the margins
var margin = {top: 60, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 80},
  width = 850 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Legend sizing
var legendRectSize = 18;                                 
var legendSpacing = 4; 


// Parse the month variable
var parseMonth = d3.timeParse("%b");
var formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b");

var formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");
var parseYear = d3.timeParse("%Y");


// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([parseMonth("Jan"), parseMonth("Dec")]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["2016", "2015"])
  .range(["#00BFFF", "#87CEFA"]);
  
// Define the line
var valueLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); })
 
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
    .attr("class", "tooltip")    
    .style("opacity", 0);

// Create the svg canvas in the "graph" div
var svg = d3.select("#graph")
        .append("svg")
        .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
        .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "svg");


var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv);
  
   // Format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Month = parseMonth(d.Month);
      d.Sales = +d.Sales;
      d.Fruit = d.Fruit;
      d.Year = formatYear(parseYear(+d.Year));
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
   .key(function(d){
     return d.Fruit;
   })
   .key(function(d){
    return d.Year;
   })
   .entries(data)

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Month; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Sales; })]);
  
  // Set up the x axis
  var xaxis = svg.append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
       .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
          .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
          .tickSize(0, 0)
          .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"))
          .tickSizeInner(0)
          .tickPadding(10));

  // Add the Y Axis
   var yaxis = svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
       .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
          .ticks(5)
          .tickSizeInner(0)
          .tickPadding(6)
          .tickSize(0, 0));
  
  // Add a label to the y axis
  svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - 60)
        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Monthly Sales")
        .attr("class", "y axis label")
  .style("font-family", "Courier New")
  .style("font-size", "11px");
  
 //Add Title
  svg.append("text")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("x", width/2)
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Fruit Sales")
        .attr("class", "y axis label")
  .style("font-family", "Courier New")
  .style("font-size", "20px");
  
  svg.append('g').classed('data-points', true);
  
  // Create a dropdown
    var fruitMenu = d3.select("#fruitDropdown")

    fruitMenu
  .append("select")
  .selectAll("option")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
  
        .attr("value", function(d){
            return d.key;
        })
        .text(function(d){
            return d.key;
        })


 
  // Function to create the initial graph
  var initialGraph = function(fruit){

   // Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
   var selectFruit = nest.filter(function(d){
                return d.key == fruit;
              })

     var selectFruitGroups = svg.selectAll(".fruitGroups")
      .data(selectFruit, function(d){
        return d ? d.key : this.key;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "fruitGroups")

  var initialPath = selectFruitGroups.selectAll(".line")
   .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("stroke", function(d){ return colors(d.key)});


  initialPath
   .attr("d", function(d){
    return valueLine(d.values)
   })
   .attr("class", "line")
      
     svg.select('g.data-points').selectAll("dot")
   .data(data.filter(function(d) { 
    return d.Fruit === fruit;
   }))
   .enter().append("circle").classed('dot', true)
   .attr("r", 3) 
   .attr("fill", function(d){ return colors(d.key)})
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
     div.transition()  
      .duration(200)  
      .style("opacity", .9);  
     div .html("Sales:" + " "  + d.Sales) 
      .style("font-family", "Courier New")
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")  
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
     })     
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {  
     div.transition()  
      .duration(500)  
      .style("opacity", 0); 
    }); 
  }

  // Create initial graph
  initialGraph("strawberry")


  // Update the data
  var updateGraph = function(fruit){

   // Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
   var selectFruit = nest.filter(function(d){
                return d.key == fruit;
              })

   // Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
     var selectFruitGroups = svg.selectAll(".fruitGroups")
      .data(selectFruit)

      // Select all the lines and transition to new positions
            selectFruitGroups.selectAll("path.line")
               .data(function(d){
                  return (d.values);
                })
                .transition()
                  .duration(1000)
                  .attr("d", function(d){
                    return valueLine(d.values)
                  });
                  
   var circles = svg.select('g.data-points').selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data.filter(function(d) { 
     return d.Fruit === fruit;
    }));

 circles
    .enter().append("circle")
    .merge(circles).classed('data-point', true)
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("fill", function(d){ return colors(d.key)})
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); });
    
  }
  
  var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')                     
          .data(colors.domain())                                   // NEW
          .enter()                                                // NEW
          .append('g')                                            // NEW
          .attr('class', 'legend')                                // NEW
          .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                     // NEW
            var height1 = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;          // NEW
            var offset =  height1 * colors.domain().length /2;     // NEW
            var horz = 37 * legendRectSize;                       // NEW
            var vert = i * height1 - offset;                       // NEW
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';        // NEW
          });                                                     // NEW

        legend.append('rect')                                     // NEW
          .attr('width', legendRectSize)                          // NEW
          .attr('height', legendRectSize)                         // NEW
          .style('fill', colors)                                   // NEW
          .style('stroke', colors);                                // NEW
          
        legend.append('text')                                     // NEW
          .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)              // NEW
          .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing) 
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });    


  // Run update function when dropdown selection changes
  fruitMenu.on('change', function(){

   // Find which fruit was selected from the dropdown
   var selectedFruit = d3.select(this)
            .select("select")
            .property("value")

        // Run update function with the selected fruit
        updateGraph(selectedFruit)


    });
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

div.tooltip { 
    position: absolute;   
    text-align: center;   
    width: 60px;     
    height: 28px;     
    padding: 2px;    
    font: 12px sans-serif;  
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;  
    border-radius: 8px;   
    pointer-events: none;   
}

.dot:hover {
      fill: black;
    }
 
.legend {                                                   /* NEW */
        font-size: 10px;                                          /* NEW */
      }                                                           /* NEW */
      rect {                                                      /* NEW */
        stroke-width: 2;                                          /* NEW */
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
  
  <body>
 <g class="data-points"></g>
    <div id = "fruitDropdown"></div>
    <div id="graph"></div>
 
    <script src="Example11.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

How can I ensure the circles take the same color as the line whilst ensuring that they update when a different fruit is selected? I'm hoping this solution will also provide a fix for the extra rectangle in the legend.

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `fill` for the circles from `colors(d.key)` to `colors(d.Year)` did the trick buddy.

Code change and the snippet:

```
.attr("fill", function(d){ return colors(d.Year)})
```

```js
var dataAsCsv = `Month,Sales,Fruit,Year
Jan,87,strawberry,2016
Feb,3,strawberry,2016
Mar,89,strawberry,2016
Apr,56,strawberry,2016
May,1,strawberry,2016
Jun,17,strawberry,2016
Jul,59,strawberry,2016
Aug,43,strawberry,2016
Sep,16,strawberry,2016
Oct,94,strawberry,2016
Nov,99,strawberry,2016
Dec,53,strawberry,2016
Jan,93,grape,2016
Feb,8,grape,2016
Mar,95,grape,2016
Apr,62,grape,2016
May,5,grape,2016
Jun,24,grape,2016
Jul,62,grape,2016
Aug,49,grape,2016
Sep,18,grape,2016
Oct,101,grape,2016
Nov,103,grape,2016
Dec,53,grape,2016
Jan,94,blueberry,2016
Feb,15,blueberry,2016
Mar,95,blueberry,2016
Apr,64,blueberry,2016
May,11,blueberry,2016
Jun,33,blueberry,2016
Jul,64,blueberry,2016
Aug,53,blueberry,2016
Sep,27,blueberry,2016
Oct,103,blueberry,2016
Nov,108,blueberry,2016
Dec,62,blueberry,2016
Jan,80,strawberry,2015
Feb,0,strawberry,2015
Mar,71,strawberry,2015
Apr,51,strawberry,2015
May,3,strawberry,2015
Jun,11,strawberry,2015
Jul,56,strawberry,2015
Aug,34,strawberry,2015
Sep,12,strawberry,2015
Oct,75,strawberry,2015
Nov,94,strawberry,2015
Dec,46,strawberry,2015
Jan,76,grape,2015
Feb,0,grape,2015
Mar,78,grape,2015
Apr,58,grape,2015
May,10,grape,2015
Jun,22,grape,2015
Jul,47,grape,2015
Aug,36,grape,2015
Sep,18,grape,2015
Oct,86,grape,2015
Nov,98,grape,2015
Dec,40,grape,2015
Jan,79,blueberry,2015
Feb,0,blueberry,2015
Mar,78,blueberry,2015
Apr,49,blueberry,2015
May,5,blueberry,2015
Jun,31,blueberry,2015
Jul,62,blueberry,2015
Aug,49,blueberry,2015
Sep,7,blueberry,2015
Oct,86,blueberry,2015
Nov,100,blueberry,2015
Dec,46,blueberry,2015`;


// Set the margins
var margin = {top: 60, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 80},
  width = 850 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Legend sizing
var legendRectSize = 18;                                 
var legendSpacing = 4; 


// Parse the month variable
var parseMonth = d3.timeParse("%b");
var formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b");

var formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");
var parseYear = d3.timeParse("%Y");


// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([parseMonth("Jan"), parseMonth("Dec")]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["2016", "2015"])
  .range(["#00BFFF", "#87CEFA"]);
  
// Define the line
var valueLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); })
 
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
    .attr("class", "tooltip")    
    .style("opacity", 0);

// Create the svg canvas in the "graph" div
var svg = d3.select("#graph")
        .append("svg")
        .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
        .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "svg");


var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv);
  
   // Format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Month = parseMonth(d.Month);
      d.Sales = +d.Sales;
      d.Fruit = d.Fruit;
      d.Year = formatYear(parseYear(+d.Year));
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
   .key(function(d){
     return d.Fruit;
   })
   .key(function(d){
    return d.Year;
   })
   .entries(data)

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Month; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Sales; })]);
  
  // Set up the x axis
  var xaxis = svg.append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
       .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
          .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
          .tickSize(0, 0)
          .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"))
          .tickSizeInner(0)
          .tickPadding(10));

  // Add the Y Axis
   var yaxis = svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
       .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
          .ticks(5)
          .tickSizeInner(0)
          .tickPadding(6)
          .tickSize(0, 0));
  
  // Add a label to the y axis
  svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - 60)
        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Monthly Sales")
        .attr("class", "y axis label")
  .style("font-family", "Courier New")
  .style("font-size", "11px");
  
 //Add Title
  svg.append("text")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("x", width/2)
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Fruit Sales")
        .attr("class", "y axis label")
  .style("font-family", "Courier New")
  .style("font-size", "20px");
  
  svg.append('g').classed('data-points', true);
  
  // Create a dropdown
    var fruitMenu = d3.select("#fruitDropdown")

    fruitMenu
  .append("select")
  .selectAll("option")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
  
        .attr("value", function(d){
            return d.key;
        })
        .text(function(d){
            return d.key;
        })


 
  // Function to create the initial graph
  var initialGraph = function(fruit){

   // Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
   var selectFruit = nest.filter(function(d){
                return d.key == fruit;
              })

     var selectFruitGroups = svg.selectAll(".fruitGroups")
      .data(selectFruit, function(d){
        return d ? d.key : this.key;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "fruitGroups")

  var initialPath = selectFruitGroups.selectAll(".line")
   .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("stroke", function(d){ return colors(d.key)});


  initialPath
   .attr("d", function(d){
    return valueLine(d.values)
   })
   .attr("class", "line")
      
     svg.select('g.data-points').selectAll("dot")
   .data(data.filter(function(d) { 
    return d.Fruit === fruit;
   }))
   .enter().append("circle").classed('dot', true)
   .attr("r", 3) 
   .attr("fill", function(d){ return colors(d.Year)})
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
     div.transition()  
      .duration(200)  
      .style("opacity", .9);  
     div .html("Sales:" + " "  + d.Sales) 
      .style("font-family", "Courier New")
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")  
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
     })     
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {  
     div.transition()  
      .duration(500)  
      .style("opacity", 0); 
    }); 
  }

  // Create initial graph
  initialGraph("strawberry")


  // Update the data
  var updateGraph = function(fruit){

   // Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
   var selectFruit = nest.filter(function(d){
                return d.key == fruit;
              })

   // Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
     var selectFruitGroups = svg.selectAll(".fruitGroups")
      .data(selectFruit)

      // Select all the lines and transition to new positions
            selectFruitGroups.selectAll("path.line")
               .data(function(d){
                  return (d.values);
                })
                .transition()
                  .duration(1000)
                  .attr("d", function(d){
                    return valueLine(d.values)
                  });
                  
   var circles = svg.select('g.data-points').selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data.filter(function(d) { 
     return d.Fruit === fruit;
    }));

 circles
    .enter().append("circle")
    .merge(circles).classed('data-point', true)
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("fill", function(d){ return colors(d.Year)})
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); });
    
  }
  
  var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')                     
          .data(colors.domain())                                   // NEW
          .enter()                                                // NEW
          .append('g')                                            // NEW
          .attr('class', 'legend')                                // NEW
          .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                     // NEW
            var height1 = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;          // NEW
            var offset =  height1 * colors.domain().length /2;     // NEW
            var horz = 37 * legendRectSize;                       // NEW
            var vert = i * height1 - offset;                       // NEW
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';        // NEW
          });                                                     // NEW

        legend.append('rect')                                     // NEW
          .attr('width', legendRectSize)                          // NEW
          .attr('height', legendRectSize)                         // NEW
          .style('fill', colors)                                   // NEW
          .style('stroke', colors);                                // NEW
          
        legend.append('text')                                     // NEW
          .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)              // NEW
          .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing) 
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });    


  // Run update function when dropdown selection changes
  fruitMenu.on('change', function(){

   // Find which fruit was selected from the dropdown
   var selectedFruit = d3.select(this)
            .select("select")
            .property("value")

        // Run update function with the selected fruit
        updateGraph(selectedFruit)


    });
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

div.tooltip { 
    position: absolute;   
    text-align: center;   
    width: 60px;     
    height: 28px;     
    padding: 2px;    
    font: 12px sans-serif;  
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;  
    border-radius: 8px;   
    pointer-events: none;   
}

.dot:hover {
      fill: black;
    }
 
.legend {                                                   /* NEW */
        font-size: 10px;                                          /* NEW */
      }                                                           /* NEW */
      rect {                                                      /* NEW */
        stroke-width: 2;                                          /* NEW */
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
  
  <body>
 <g class="data-points"></g>
    <div id = "fruitDropdown"></div>
    <div id="graph"></div>
 
    <script src="Example11.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Also, if you're up for suggestions, I'd like you to arrange `fruitGroups` and corresponding `circles` within the same group. I'd suggest you have a structure as follows:

```
<g class="fruitGroups">
   <g class="2015">
     <path></path>
     <circle class="dot"></circle>
     ...
   </g>
   <g class="2016">
     <path></path>
     <circle></circle>
     ...
   </g>
</g>
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS**

To change colors for the fruits, as you mentioned in the comments, I've used separate color domains and here's how it is used in determining the color of the `path` in the `updateGraph` function.

For `path`:

```
.style('stroke', function(d) { if (fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d.key)} else if (fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d.key)} else {return colors2(d.key)}});
```

For circles:

```
.style("fill", function(d){ if (d.Fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d.Year)} else if (d.Fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d.Year)} else {return colors2(d.Year)}})
```

For legends:

```
// rerender legend rects
svg.selectAll('.legend rect')
  .style('fill', function(d) { if (fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d)} else if (fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d)} else {return colors2(d)}})
  .style('stroke', function(d) { if (fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d)} else if (fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d)} else {return colors2(d)}});
```

Here's a snippet doing all of the above:

```js
var dataAsCsv = `Month,Sales,Fruit,Year
Jan,87,strawberry,2016
Feb,3,strawberry,2016
Mar,89,strawberry,2016
Apr,56,strawberry,2016
May,1,strawberry,2016
Jun,17,strawberry,2016
Jul,59,strawberry,2016
Aug,43,strawberry,2016
Sep,16,strawberry,2016
Oct,94,strawberry,2016
Nov,99,strawberry,2016
Dec,53,strawberry,2016
Jan,93,grape,2016
Feb,8,grape,2016
Mar,95,grape,2016
Apr,62,grape,2016
May,5,grape,2016
Jun,24,grape,2016
Jul,62,grape,2016
Aug,49,grape,2016
Sep,18,grape,2016
Oct,101,grape,2016
Nov,103,grape,2016
Dec,53,grape,2016
Jan,94,blueberry,2016
Feb,15,blueberry,2016
Mar,95,blueberry,2016
Apr,64,blueberry,2016
May,11,blueberry,2016
Jun,33,blueberry,2016
Jul,64,blueberry,2016
Aug,53,blueberry,2016
Sep,27,blueberry,2016
Oct,103,blueberry,2016
Nov,108,blueberry,2016
Dec,62,blueberry,2016
Jan,80,strawberry,2015
Feb,0,strawberry,2015
Mar,71,strawberry,2015
Apr,51,strawberry,2015
May,3,strawberry,2015
Jun,11,strawberry,2015
Jul,56,strawberry,2015
Aug,34,strawberry,2015
Sep,12,strawberry,2015
Oct,75,strawberry,2015
Nov,94,strawberry,2015
Dec,46,strawberry,2015
Jan,76,grape,2015
Feb,0,grape,2015
Mar,78,grape,2015
Apr,58,grape,2015
May,10,grape,2015
Jun,22,grape,2015
Jul,47,grape,2015
Aug,36,grape,2015
Sep,18,grape,2015
Oct,86,grape,2015
Nov,98,grape,2015
Dec,40,grape,2015
Jan,79,blueberry,2015
Feb,0,blueberry,2015
Mar,78,blueberry,2015
Apr,49,blueberry,2015
May,5,blueberry,2015
Jun,31,blueberry,2015
Jul,62,blueberry,2015
Aug,49,blueberry,2015
Sep,7,blueberry,2015
Oct,86,blueberry,2015
Nov,100,blueberry,2015
Dec,46,blueberry,2015`;


// Set the margins
var margin = {top: 60, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 80},
  width = 850 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Legend sizing
var legendRectSize = 18;                                 
var legendSpacing = 4; 


// Parse the month variable
var parseMonth = d3.timeParse("%b");
var formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b");

var formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");
var parseYear = d3.timeParse("%Y");

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([parseMonth("Jan"), parseMonth("Dec")]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["2016", "2015"])
  .range(["#00BFFF", "#87CEFA"]);
  
var colors1 = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["2016", "2015"])
  .range(["red", "orange"]);

var colors2 = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["2016", "2015"])
  .range(["darkgreen", "lightgreen"]);

// Define the line
var valueLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); })
 
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
    .attr("class", "tooltip")    
    .style("opacity", 0);

// Create the svg canvas in the "graph" div
var svg = d3.select("#graph")
        .append("svg")
        .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
        .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "svg");


var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv);
  
   // Format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Month = parseMonth(d.Month);
      d.Sales = +d.Sales;
      d.Fruit = d.Fruit;
      d.Year = formatYear(parseYear(+d.Year));
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
   .key(function(d){
     return d.Fruit;
   })
   .key(function(d){
    return d.Year;
   })
   .entries(data)

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Month; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Sales; })]);
  
  // Set up the x axis
  var xaxis = svg.append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
       .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
          .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
          .tickSize(0, 0)
          .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"))
          .tickSizeInner(0)
          .tickPadding(10));

  // Add the Y Axis
   var yaxis = svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
       .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
          .ticks(5)
          .tickSizeInner(0)
          .tickPadding(6)
          .tickSize(0, 0));
  
  // Add a label to the y axis
  svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - 60)
        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Monthly Sales")
        .attr("class", "y axis label")
  .style("font-family", "Courier New")
  .style("font-size", "11px");
  
 //Add Title
  svg.append("text")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("x", width/2)
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Fruit Sales")
        .attr("class", "y axis label")
  .style("font-family", "Courier New")
  .style("font-size", "20px");
  
  svg.append('g').classed('data-points', true);
  
  // Create a dropdown
    var fruitMenu = d3.select("#fruitDropdown")

    fruitMenu
  .append("select")
  .selectAll("option")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
  
        .attr("value", function(d){
            return d.key;
        })
        .text(function(d){
            return d.key;
        })


 
  // Function to create the initial graph
  var initialGraph = function(fruit){

   // Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
   var selectFruit = nest.filter(function(d){
                return d.key == fruit;
              })

     var selectFruitGroups = svg.selectAll(".fruitGroups")
      .data(selectFruit, function(d){
        return d ? d.key : this.key;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "fruitGroups")

  var initialPath = selectFruitGroups.selectAll(".line")
   .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("stroke", function(d){ if (fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d.key)} else if (fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d.key)} else {return colors2(d.key)}});


  initialPath
   .attr("d", function(d){
    return valueLine(d.values)
   })
   .attr("class", "line")
      
     svg.select('g.data-points').selectAll("dot")
   .data(data.filter(function(d) { 
    return d.Fruit === fruit;
   }))
   .enter().append("circle").classed('dot', true)
   .attr("r", 3) 
   .attr("fill", function(d){ if (d.Fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d.Year)} else if (d.Fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d.Year)} else {return colors2(d.Year)}})
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
     div.transition()  
      .duration(200)  
      .style("opacity", .9);  
     div .html("Sales:" + " "  + d.Sales) 
      .style("font-family", "Courier New")
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")  
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
     })     
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {  
     div.transition()  
      .duration(500)  
      .style("opacity", 0); 
    }); 
  }

  // Create initial graph
  initialGraph("strawberry");


  // Update the data
  var updateGraph = function(fruit){

   // Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
   var selectFruit = nest.filter(function(d){
                return d.key == fruit;
              })

   // Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
     var selectFruitGroups = svg.selectAll(".fruitGroups")
      .data(selectFruit)
      // Select all the lines and transition to new positions
            selectFruitGroups.selectAll("path.line")
               .data(function(d){
                  return (d.values);
                })
                .transition()
                  .duration(1000)
                  .attr("d", function(d){
                    return valueLine(d.values)
                  }).style('stroke', function(d) { if (fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d.key)} else if (fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d.key)} else {return colors2(d.key)}});
                  
   var circles = svg.select('g.data-points').selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data.filter(function(d) { 
     return d.Fruit === fruit;
    }));

 circles
    .enter().append("circle")
    .merge(circles).classed('data-point', true)
    .attr("r", 3)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .style("fill", function(d){ if (d.Fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d.Year)} else if (d.Fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d.Year)} else {return colors2(d.Year)}})
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(+d.Sales); });
    
    // rerender legend rects
    svg.selectAll('.legend rect')
      .style('fill', function(d) { if (fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d)} else if (fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d)} else {return colors2(d)}})
      .style('stroke', function(d) { if (fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d)} else if (fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d)} else {return colors2(d)}});
  }
  
  var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')                     
          .data(colors.domain())                                   // NEW
          .enter()                                                // NEW
          .append('g')                                            // NEW
          .attr('class', 'legend')                                // NEW
          .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                     // NEW
            var height1 = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;          // NEW
            var offset =  height1 * colors.domain().length /2;     // NEW
            var horz = 37 * legendRectSize;                       // NEW
            var vert = i * height1 - offset;                       // NEW
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';        // NEW
          });                                                     // NEW

        legend.append('rect')                                     // NEW
          .attr('width', legendRectSize)                          // NEW
          .attr('height', legendRectSize)                         // NEW
          .style('fill', colors)                                   // NEW
          .style('stroke', colors);                                // NEW
          
        legend.append('text')                                     // NEW
          .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)              // NEW
          .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing) 
    .style("font-family", "Courier New")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });    


  // Run update function when dropdown selection changes
  fruitMenu.on('change', function(){

   // Find which fruit was selected from the dropdown
   var selectedFruit = d3.select(this)
            .select("select")
            .property("value")

        // Run update function with the selected fruit
        updateGraph(selectedFruit)


    });
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

div.tooltip { 
    position: absolute;   
    text-align: center;   
    width: 60px;     
    height: 28px;     
    padding: 2px;    
    font: 12px sans-serif;  
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;  
    border-radius: 8px;   
    pointer-events: none;   
}

.dot:hover {
      fill: black;
    }
 
.legend {                                                   /* NEW */
        font-size: 10px;                                          /* NEW */
      }                                                           /* NEW */
      rect {                                                      /* NEW */
        stroke-width: 2;                                          /* NEW */
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
  
  <body>
 <g class="data-points"></g>
    <div id = "fruitDropdown"></div>
    <div id="graph"></div>
 
    <script src="Example11.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

*Improvements that you can work on:*

1. Color domains :)
2. Render the legends once the `path`s are transitioned (use the `.on('end, function(){})` callback. If you aren't sure on how to use that, refer my answer: [Transition on end callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896661/d3-y-axis-label-position/46897908#46897908)
3. Fix bugs (if any)

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you! I should have asked this above, but I also thought it would be good to change the colors of the lines when I filter for different fruits. To do this I tried the following: .attr("stroke", function(d){ 
    if (d.Fruit == "strawberry") {return colors(d.key)}
    else if (d.Fruit == "grape") {return colors1(d.key)}
    else {return colors2(d.key)}});

Comment: Glad I could help. Okay, this would work within the `initialGraph` BUT not within `updateGraph` as `d.Fruit` is `undefined` in that case. Try using `if(fruit === 'grape') { return colors1(d.key)}...` (i.e. using the `fruit` passed to the updateGraph function. I tried this and it worked (with 3 separate color domains). Also, make sure you update the legends in this case. If you face any difficulties in doing that, let me know. I'll help you out (after work).

Comment: Okay so I've left `initialGraph` as is and changed `updateGraph`. However still no luck. I added the .style(...) to var initialPath and var var selectFruitGroups - is this correct? Would you be able to edit the snippet above? Thanks for your time - greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Done. Check out the new snippet. Happy to help mate.